# Spring Boot dynamically provide String Beans based on custom annotation from external library

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ioc

**Background**: Let's say I'm in the process of migrating code from old code to Spring Boot 2 applications.
The old code had its own IoC mechanism and I'd like to reuse old libraries in new Spring app without modifying the libraries codebase.

Libraries code used field-injections only. It used annotation similar to `@Value` for injecting some properties, let's say `@InjectString`. Also every field also had `@Inject` annotation on top. So all libraries that I'd like to use look more or less like this:

```
package com.mylibrary;

public class LibraryA {

    @Inject
    @InjectString("db.properties.poolEnabled")
    private String poolEnabled;
...
```

**Assumption**:

- all properties like `db.properties.poolEnabled` are already present in `System.getProperties()`.
- the `LibraryA` class is already under Spring IoC control, it's just missing the required field bean:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @com.mylibrary.InjectString(name="db.properties.poolEnabled")}
```

**Question**:
How can I reuse old code and let Spring know what values to put dynamically into the fields with `@Inject` based on `@InjectString` name (which can be retrieved from `System.getProperty`?

I was thinking about 3 potential solutions:

1. during beans construction, let Spring know that when it's looking for a Bean of type String and it the field has `@InjectString` annotation, it can get a value from `System.getProperty()` as the bean value.
2. during class scan, take all fields with `@InjectString` and somehow append there a `@Value` annotations and maybe Spring will know what to insert there
3. scan for all fields annotated with `@InjectString`, create String named beans for all of them and append `@Resource(name="...")` to every fields bean declaration

Which idea sounds the best and which Spring classes will help with implementation?

So far I'd probably prefer solution 1), as it sounds like a single Spring class override.
In solution 2) and 3) I'm missing the Spring classes I can override during IoC building to provide extra beans definitions dynamically - do you know what can I use?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `@Value` javadoc we will see hint, that processing is done in [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L161)  and binding is done in `AutowireCandidateResolver`.

So, I would try with registering additional `BeanPostProcessor` that will have you `@InjectString` set as [`autowiredAnnotationTypes`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L185).
Then register [`QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java#L127) with this annotation.